# FileProvider - Can't save file due to FileNotFoundException: /Download/TempFile.html (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

Seems like FileProvider is now required for Android N, so I'm trying to implement FileProvider to save a file from the network into a local temp location, and then I need to read this temp file.

I've done this to setup the FileProvider:

Manifest.xml:

```
</application>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Then I have a `provider_paths.xml` file in my `res/xml` folder, with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="Download" path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

Finally, this is the java code I have to create the temp file:

```
try {

    final File imagePath = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "Download");
    final File newFile = new File(imagePath, filename + "." + filePrefix);

    final Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", newFile);

    final File tempFile = new File(contentUri.getPath());

    tempFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    return tempFile;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

The line of `final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile);` throws the exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Download/TempFile.html (No such file or directory)`

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Update/Edit:

The current approach to save the file places the file here:
`/storage/emulated/0/Download/TempFile.html`

This is fine until I try to consume it with an Intent, like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), fileType.getMimeType());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

This then throws this exception:

`android.os.FileUriExposedException:file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/TempFile.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems like FileProvider is now required for Android N

It will be used commonly, but only for making content available to other apps. Your needs do not seem to include making content available to other apps.

> I'm trying to implement FileProvider to save a file from the network into a local temp location

You have no code in your question that has anything to do with a network.

> Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Calling `getPath()` on a `Uri` is generally useless. At best, it might be useful if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. `FileProvider` is designed specifically to *not* give you a `Uri` with a `file` scheme, but rather a `content` scheme. The path of that `Uri` will not directly represent a file on the device, any more than `/questions/39296553/fileprovider-cant-save-file-due-to-filenotfoundexception-download-tempfile` (the path of the URL of this Web page) represents a path to a file on your computer.

Beyond that, you do not need a `FileProvider` to make a temporary file, and you do need a `FileProvider` to download content over a network.

---

**UPDATE** (based upon question update)

First, replace `Uri.fromFile(file)` with `FileProvider.getUriForFile(file)` in your `Intent` logic.

Second, if you really are storing the file in `/storage/emulated/0/Download/TempFile.html`, you would need to use `external-path` in your `FileProvider` configuration, not `files-path`. `files-path` would be if you were storing your downloaded file in `getFilesDir()`. Your `/storage/emulated/0/Download/TempFile.html` path would appear to be off of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: In reality, what I'm trying to fix is this: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/TempFile.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData() and the fix for this is to use FileProvider, right?
I've even found some questions you had to google about this, and that seems to be a mandatory thing now in Android N, targetSdk 24.

The file is created with a content I'm passing to the try block, which I removed for the question.
What I need to do is create a file, and save it locally.

Comment: @TooManyEduardos: "the fix for this is to use FileProvider, right?" -- yes, but only for whatever is triggering that exception. There's nothing in the code in your question that should cause that, because you are not invoking some other app. Download the file normally, to some location that you are serving via `FileProvider`. When you try to give the content to *some other app*, then use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/DownloadNotify) demonstrates this, where I use `getUriForFile()` only for a `Notification`.

Comment: The "newFile" is: "/data/user/0/com.myapp.android.apps.myapp/files/Download/TempFile.html", and the "contentUri" is "content://com.myapp.android.apps.myapp.provider/Download/TempFile.html" so this is also very odd

Comment: @TooManyEduardos: No, that is expected. You may wish to read [the documentation for `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Comment: "Download the file normally, to some location that you are serving via FileProvider". How do I do this part?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos: I don't know. You just indicated that this is a "file from the network". If you mean a "file served by a Web server over HTTPS", use `HttpURLConnection`, or OkHttp, or Volley, or the independent packaged library for Apache HttpClient, or whatever other HTTP client API suits you. None of that will involve the `FileProvider`.

Comment: The file is downloaded fine, and placed into a new File object. That's not the problem. If you have a second, look at the update I made to the question to see how we're using it with intent. Basically we need to open a pdf reader with the file, so we need to pass the file to a new intent

Comment: would you happen to know why third party apps (like Google PDF reader) can't read the file? The pdf reader app opens, but there's no content. This works on M with the same reader. The only difference is the file location in the intent changes from `dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/TempFile.pdf` (in M), to `dat=content://com.myapp.android.apps.myapp.provider/download/TempFile.pdf` (in N)

Comment: @TooManyEduardos: Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`.

Comment: I have it already. These are the flags, and file setup of the intent:
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(AncestryApplication.getAppContext(), AncestryApplication.getAppContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file), fileType.getMimeType());
        }`

Comment: @TooManyEduardos: Use either one `setFlags()` or use `addFlags()`. Your second `setFlags()` wipes out your first `setFlags()`.

Comment: Just bumped into the same problem: my photo providing app cannot write into the file given by a client app through a content Uri. I can see that the problem is, as @CommonsWare pointed, is applying getPath() to a Uri. But how should I write into the file then? (All wrtiting methods seems to accept File which should be converted from Uri). Thanks !

Comment: @rommex: Use a `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()`. Works for `file` and `content` schemes. Use the resulting `OutputStream` as you would the `FileOutputStream`.